# how to import java source into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Sorry for probably too novice question

I have folder on file system that contains java sources, like that:
C:\project\src\com\sun\blahblah...\Main.java

Main class is in the package com.sun.blahblah... and contain public static void main method, i.e. everything is well-formed :)

I want to import entire folder C:\project\src then I want to right-click Main.java and run it as Java application.

What kind of import should I select in Eclipse (from file-system or what)?

Note I don't want to create copy of my sources. They are under SVN already. I want to edit/run existent soures.

Comment: You shouldn't actually use the `com.sun` package unless your code is the property of Sun Microsystems. I assume you were just using that as an example, but just in case...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create a new Java project in Eclipse
2. Select c:\project as the root folder of the project (create a project from existing source)

Comment: And how to run app imported this way in debug mode?

Answer (score 5):

Create a new project in your Eclipse workspace (or use an existing project)

Rigth-click on the project

Select “**Import…**” / “**General**” / “**File System**”

Choose the **directory**, select the **files** and **IMPORT**